# Troubleshooting Google reCaptcha v.3 > Why no stats, even though icon appears on form?

Tags: web-development

I've just installed (well, a PHP programmer did it for me) Google reCaptcha (v. 3, Invisible) on a form page. The page's PHP code performs a sendmail and populates an external database upon submission. In recent years, the page has attracted bots and spammers, so a reCaptcha was called for.

The Dashboard page (at Google, where the reCaptcha is configured) doesn't offer any tools for verification of the tool, and that seems like a shortcoming. In any case, it does have a link to download the Analytics. However, after a month of use, I'm still getting spammy submissions.

Most perplexing, though, is that the .CSV file I download has no records, only the column headings.

Part of my testing: I pulled the "security" settings ("Dashboard > Advanced") all the way down, and this prompted a visual challenge. And the reCaptcha icon is displayed on the form page.

Can anyone suggest how I can effectively troubleshoot this? I can't find anything in the Docs about how often the analytics gets refreshed, but, even on a day with a handful of submissions, it's always empty.